# QA tool with feature for automatic recording of user actions when manual testing

Tags: manual-testing, action-recording

In our company we have a problem with the testers: They often fail to provide enough information to reproduce a defect. Is there a tool that automatically records every action of a tester? For example:

1. Go to screen X
2. Click button Y
3. Type "Some text"

I know that JIRA has a browser plugin to take screenshots, but it doesn't record actions.

Comment: Do you have to go the tool option or can you educate your testers?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) has two recording options. Exploratory testing in MTM allows testers to record everything they do, they can add commentary and screenshots etc throughout the test session. During an exploratory test session the recording can easily be converted into a fault report (it can be as simple as click one button, enter a title, click save). Of course the fault report and recording can be edited if desired. Fault reports can also be used to quickly create new test cases. MTM can also be used for recording the steps of a formal test case so they can be played back as semi-automated tests.

The Microsoft tools give a complete Application Lifecycle Management (ALM) system. Thus MTM along with TFS and Visual Studio provide facilities for managing requirements, work items, test cases, test results, source code and more. Work items and test cases can be assigned to people. One downside of MTM is the cost per user.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to record actions for a desktop app I think [Problem Steps Recorder](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-use-problem-steps-recorder%20Problem%20Steps%20Recorder) will work.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium IDE records all actions. You can playback a session.

Comment: Can it be used to record desktop software testing?

Comment: No, Selenium is for browsers

Answer (score 1):

I think you should educate your tester/qa to be clear when reporting issues including steps on how to reproduce the problems. It is a problems about the people not about lacking of tools.

Comment: I disagree.  You can do your best with training, but many times steps to reproduce are not clear, screenshots are missing the URL, etc.  I often times find myself needing more information.  A tool can be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are such tools.

For example Monosnap records video from users's desktop so you can use that to record also non-browser applications. Cool thing in Monosnap is that is quite light, allows entering figures on top of the video ( like red ellipses to point where to look ), creates mp4 files which most users can view without installing additional programs and for Meliora Testlab users, it integrates to tool allowing pushing the videos automatically to defects.

HP Quality Center (ALM) comes with installable video recording tool. Works well with QC, but playback requires the same app to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [qTest eXplorer](http://www.qasymphony.com/platform/exploratory-testing.html) that

- Automatically records every step and screen of software testing
  execution
- Allows users to take notes and annotate screens while testing
- Lets users submit detailed defect records to defect tracking tools
- Automatically writes test cases to Excel or directly to qTest (test management platform)
- Generates session reports that meets the needs of session-based
  testing
- Captures detailed testing and quality metrics for analytics
- Creates a complete recording of the test session to share with other
  team members or archive for future audit

Comment: Never heard of this one, but looks interesting. Have you used it in your company? Did it improve the process?

Comment: Long ago we had used an early variant of the tool. It used to work as advertised but at the same time we felt edits were necessary. We had tried for automatic documentation but for things like bug reporting it can certainly be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need some application which can capture screen, if this is the case you case use  'jing' tool. Jing captures anything you see on your computer screen, as an image or short video, and lets you share it instantly the steps to replicate for developers

You can also register it for free and test it with the limit of space and buy it if you like it.

I am successfully using this tool in my current project.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

SteerU Step Recorder is the best tool for what you need.

It records all steps including Enter Value into fields,Press Button , Drag & Drop etc' and automatically export record into a ready to use Word Document which you can use to export to another format ,send by e-mail....

[Steps Recorder](http://stepsrecorder.com)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for 2018

Mac:

- QuickTime is a good built in option for screen recording.

Windows:

- powerpoint now provides this
- camtasia
- iSpring Free Cam

Linux:

- Kazam
- Open Broadcaster Software Studio

General:

- YouTube streaming

Answer (score -1):

Try imacros for web and winparrot for windows.
Imacros is helpful when you have to do repetitive task or filling a form multiple times. We can also use excel for providing different values everytime the form is submitted. You can say it's a small regression but very handy tool for testers. But it can only help with web application. For windows application i suggest winparrot. About winparrot: Start recording your tasks or your entries, WinParrot will replay them immediately without programming you could run a screen grab tool to capture an image, then do something with the resulting file.

Comment: Could you give some more information about the tool you're suggesting? There isn't enough information in this response to be really helpful.

Comment: @KatePaulk Imacros is helpful when you have to do repetitive task or filling a form multiple times. We can also use excel for providing different values everytime the form is submitted. You can a small regression tool for testers. But it can only help with web application. For windows application i suggest winparrot. About winparrot: Start recording your tasks or your entries, WinParrot will replay them immediately without programming .... "You could run a screen grab tool to capture an image, then do something with the resulting file.

Comment: please update your answer with that information.

Answer (score -1):

Place a camera behind tester's back.

Comment: Hi Marian. Is this a sarcastic answer or was it intended to be real? If it is a real answer, you might want to expand on it a bit.

Comment: No, I'm 100% seriously.

Comment: Hmm - could you explain how you would break down which features passed testing and which ones didn't based on this footage?

Comment: the question was "to provide enough information to reproduce a defect" - and my solution is the only way to do it no matter what happened to the device-under-test (it could reset, segfault, burn, melt whatever)