# Test management tool/plugin which provides options to screen record manual test as you execute

Tags: manual-testing, action-recording

I am looking for a Test management tool or plugin (which I can use in the test management tool) that provides an option to screen record all the actions of my manual test steps as each test is executed.

Comment: What tools have you explored so far and how they don't fit your purpose?

Comment: See https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9360/qa-tool-with-feature-for-automatic-recording-of-user-actions-when-manual-testing